# Sprite kit player and enemy collisions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i've been looking around trying to find out how to have my player and enemy collide. I have an attack button set up and need to have it so when the button is pressed the enemy in front of the player is removed from screen. How would i set up the collisions, and how would i have it only do the collision while the button is pressed?

i have tried using this code for the collision, but i don't think it has any effect.

```
//physicsbody for player and enemies
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var bodyA = SKPhysicsBody()
    var bodyB = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "player" {
        bodyA = contact.bodyA
        bodyB = contact.bodyB
    } else  {
        bodyA = contact.bodyB
        bodyB = contact.bodyA
    }
    //Player hits the rocket and dies and also remove the rocket
    if bodyA.node?.name == "player" && bodyB.node?.name == "enemy" {
        bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
        bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()


        //After player dies go to death scene
        let gameOver = GameOverScene(size:CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536), won:  false)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOver)

    }

}
```

then this is the player:

```
 func createPlayer(_ position: CGPoint) { //This is the method that creates the player on screen. You must pass this method the position you want the sprite spawned. Or maybe you can do it somewhere else in Swift, I dunno.

    //graphic stuff
    //let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam1") //create variable with graphic assigned to it
    let player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture) //give player the graphic
    player.size = CGSize(width: 175, height: 200) //player sprite size
    player.zPosition = 20
    player.name = "player"
    //physics stuff
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size: player.size) //Set up pixel-perfect collision mesh for the player
    player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true //Stop the player from being affected by gravity
    player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.PLAYER


    //spawny stuff
    insertChild(player, at: 0) //spawn player
    player.position = position //move player to position passed into this method
    playerNode = player //Create a node where the player is, filled by the player itself... Like a D.Va ult! The call mech one, not the self-destruct one.
    /*
    let frame2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam2")
    let frame3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam3")
    let frame4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ttam4")

    */
    let animation = SKAction.animate(with: [playerTexture, frame2, frame3, frame4], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let runForever = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)

    player.run(runForever)

}
```

and this is the enemy:

```
//Create enemy - slime
func spawnEnemy() {

    //Call the enemy variable and sprite
    let enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Slime1")
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyTexture)
    enemy.size = CGSize(width: 175, height: 175)
    enemy.zPosition = 10
    //Collision with the enemy
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    enemyNode = enemy

    //Randomly place the enemy on screen and move
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 2100, y: 325)
    enemy.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTexture, size: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true




    //Add enemy node to screen.
    addChild(enemy)

    let frame2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Slime2")
    let frame3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Slime3")
    let animation = SKAction.animate(with: [enemyTexture, frame2, frame3, frame2], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let runForever = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)

    enemy.run(runForever)



    //Set the enemy to move in a single direction:
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(x: -enemy.size.width/2, duration: 10.0)

    //Remove enemy from screen when action is complete:
    let actionRemove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    enemy.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionRemove]))

}
```

Comment: Let's try to narrow down the possible issues.  do you see all the sprites you expect to see in your scene in the first place?  Do the player and enemy appear to be colliding visually?  If you set a breakpoint in your `didBegin` function, do you actually hit that breakpoint?

Comment: as of right now i have commented the bodyA and bodyB contacts. i have my friend here working with me as well as i try to figure this out. i was having a problem with the enemies physics box at first(wasn't showing up or even working in game scene) but that has been resolved. They both collide in the scene now when testing, however it will not activate any code for it as of right now

Comment: UPDATE: we have the player being hit by the slime now and removing him from the scene. now i need a way of having the button destroy the enemy when close to the player

Comment: problem solved, we have found out what to do :D

Comment: It might be worth updating the question or adding an answer yourself if you think the trouble you ran into is something that other devs might hit as well.

Comment: i just didn't have all the code needed for the bodyA(or B).contact. I needed to have the player or the enemy check to either be bodyA or bodyB. i couldn't just have it say it was bodyA. I think that it wouldn't be a problem most run in to, unless they're as new as me

Answer (score 0):

To have the attack button destroy the enemy, implement `touchesBegan` and if the attack button is pressed, set a flag:

`attacking = true`

(Define `attacking` first : `var attacking = false` in your property definitions)

and in `touchesEnded`, set `attacking = false` if the touch on the attck button ended.

Then, in your `didBegin`, only destroy the player if the attack flag is not set. If it is set (i.e. the player and the slime collide whilst the attack button is pressed), destroy just the slime, add some score etc.

```
//Player hits the rocket and dies and also remove the rocket
if bodyA.node?.name == "player" && bodyB.node?.name == "enemy" {    
    switch attacking {
    case false:
        bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
        bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()

        //After player dies go to death scene
        let gameOver = GameOverScene(size:CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536), won:  false)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOver)
    case true:
        let enemy = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.ENEMY ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node
        enemy.removeFromParent()
        score += 1
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the 'rocket' in your comment is the enemy node which is the slime? :-) I didn't see a `categoryBitMask` set for the enemy - is there one? I assumed it was `ColliderType.ENEMY`

This block of code in your `didBegin:` is redundant:

```
var bodyA = SKPhysicsBody()
var bodyB = SKPhysicsBody()
if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "player" {
    bodyA = contact.bodyA
    bodyB = contact.bodyB
} else  {
    bodyA = contact.bodyB
    bodyB = contact.bodyA
}
```

as you never appear to use the `bodyA` and `bodyB` variables that you set. If you do use them later, then this might make more sense:

```
if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "player" {
    player = contact.bodyA
    enemy = contact.bodyB
} else  {
    enemy = contact.bodyB
    player = contact.bodyA
}
```

and then this line of code:

```
        let enemy = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.ENEMY ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node
```

could be removed from the `case true:` block.